# Calculating the time to travel 100 miles

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A train has an acceleration and deceleration of 10 miles per hour squared, and it has to travel 100 miles. It has a max speed of 100 miles per hour. How do you determine it's maximum speed in that journey, and the time that it takes to make the journey. (I know its  >1 hour!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  The train will accelerate at its maximum for 50 miles, then decelerate for 50 miles (as long as it doesn't hit the max speed) by symmetry.  Under constant acceleration, you have $s=\frac 12 at^2$.  Then you need twice this time.  Plug in the constants you are given.

Comment: Ah, but how do you know it didn't hit it's max speed. That piece of information is obvious here but I need to know that I'm calculating a triangle rather than a trapezoid.

Comment: Once you have $t$ this way, you can compute the max speed from $v=at$.  If it does, then it accelerates up to max speed, using $t=\frac va$ and distance $s=\frac 12 at^2$, then cruises at max speed until time to slow down symmetrically.

Comment: @kurtnelle: In particular, it takes $500$ miles for the train to reach maximum speed at maximum acceleration starting from rest, so maximum speed won't be reached here.

Comment: @Cameron, ah. now that's logical! Thanks to both of you. (duh kurt)